# C++ Memory Leak Using STL Containers

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stl

The following code is giving me a memory leak (using Visual Studio):

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Listener {};

struct Subject
{
    std::vector<Listener*> listeners;
};

int main(void)
{
    Subject subject;
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 1;
}
```

I presume this is because the STL vector container is using memory on the heap when the `Subject` class is instantiated. How do I ensure that the vector container is destroyed when the program exits? (I've tried deleting the container in the `Subject` destructor, but that doesn't seem to work).

Comment: -1 to MS for naming this function `DumpMemoryLeaks` instead of `ReportAllocatedMemory`.

Comment: `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` detects leaks by counting news and making sure they all match. Because `subject` never goes out of scope, I'm guessing it is counted as an outstanding reference. Try `int main(void) {{Subject subject;}_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); return 1}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `vector` *is* destroyed when the program exits, you don't need to ensure it. You *do* need to ensure that `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` is called after that destruction if you don't want it to report the allocated memory as "leaked":

```
int main()
{
    { Subject subject; }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This seems to work. Should one always enclose their code in curly braces when using `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`? (first time using it).

Comment: @JamesB The issue is that doesn't report "memory leaks", it reports allocated memory. If you want that allocated memory to represent leaks, you need to ensure that you call it after all destructors have run.

Comment: Alternatively you could call `_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );` at the beginning of your `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<Listener*> listeners;` will not free the members of Listeners. You'd have to delete each of the listeners that are inside the vector, using something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) delete listeners[i]
```

Personally, I avoid such issues by using smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Listener>> listeners
```

_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks detects leaks by counting news and making sure they all match. Because subject never goes out of scope, I'm guessing it is counted as an outstanding reference. Try `int main(void) {{Subject subject;}_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); return 1}`

Comment: Good general advice; but it doesn't explain why the posted code, which doesn't create any listeners, reports a leak.

Comment: Good advice. I actually tried that, and understand why one would use unique pointers, just couldn't work out why it was still showing allocated memory. As you pointed out in your comment, I need to enclose in curly braces to ensure the destructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `Listener` destructor destroys everything it needs to. All the STL container does is invoke the destructor of the object it is holding. It is still your responsibility to handle memory in the class itself.

To be more specific, anything declared with a `new` or `malloc` in the class must be freed by the destructor. The STL container won't know how to delete that.

Comment: That won't free any allocated `Listener` objects. `Subject` needs a destructor that frees those.